# I've create a PostGres DB in my heroku app with no users. Now I've added users to my app. How can I copy the DB to one of the users?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I've made one app for my personal use in  Heroku (without Users). I've used it since 2 mounths ago, so I have my personal application data in the Heroku postgres DB.

Now, I want to open the app to other people, so I've added Devise gem to create Users and I've create one new user for my use. But my question is; how can I copy my old DB in my new user?

I've tried:

```
heroku pg:backups:capture
heroku pg:backups:download
```

and later;

```
pg_restore ..........
```

in my local DB to try to copy the old DB in my new LOCAL user. I've used PGadmin3 to make the copy but I'could not.

How must I do it?
Thank's.

Comment: Your attempts look good. Did you try to run `pg_restore` with right [options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-pgrestore.html)?

Comment: Yes I do; `pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -U postgres -h localhost -d CigBackCount_development latest.dump.3`. But I've not found and option to restore the complete old DB in only one part of my new user. Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've solved not using;

```
heroku pg:backups:capture
heroku pg:backups:download    
pg_restore
```

I've fixed it with the big help that Heroku support gave me. 
It was not a problem with the backup restore option. It was as simple as give an user_id to all my data in the DB.
I've added one user_id for every table in my DB and then assign the user_id to all of them.

```
rails generate migration AddUserRefToPacks user:references
rails generate migration AddUserRefToCigs user:references
```

And then;

```
rails db:migrate
```

When the migration is finished you must run the rails console;

```
rails c
```

And assign my new user_id to all my packs and cigs.

```
Cig.all.each do |cig|
  cig.user_id = 2
  cig.save
end
```

And same for Packs.

That's all.
Thanks.